# Access GCS bucket from another project

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

How do I access Google Cloud Storage bucket (in a project) from another project ? I have sufficient permissions to manage both projects. I am programming in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCS bucket names are globally unique. You can specify any bucket name from any project, and if your account has access to it, the call will just work.